# Running Anti-Virus Software on SharePoint 2013 WFE and DB Servers

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, anti-virus

I have been advised by our infrastructure team (that does not do any of the SharePoint administration) that they will be installing anti-virus software on both the test and production environments of my new SharePoint 2013 farm. They have asked me to determine if there are any issues with anti-virus software and SharePoint. I found the article below which indicates that this can be a bit of an issue if the particular AV software does not support the AV API for SharePoint. It looks like there are only a couple that do (according to the list in the article below).

> http://www.harbar.net/archive/2013/02/22/Antivirus-and-SharePoint-2013.aspx

I had read somewhere that Microsoft was dropping Forefront for SharePoint Portal servers which doesn't leave a whole lot of options if it's true.

Does anyone have any guidance on this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Installing the AV on the server cause some performance issue and some time access denied when AV scanning the files in 14/15 hives and user trying to access it, will get access denied.

You have to make sure you exclude certain folder from the AV virus.Check the [this KB](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/952167) for more details about the folder list.

also check this post, may guide you more.
http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/bab1a929-d98e-40a8-9a85-5ccc0177f3cc/onprem-antivirus-solution-for-sharepoint-2013?forum=sharepointgeneral

Comment: Thank you so much Waqas. This is exactly the type of feedback I was hoping to get. I'm going to mark this as the answer so you get the credit for it even though I hope others respond as well.